# x509 How to find the extensions bytes length?

Tags: java, ssl, x509certificate

Currently I'm reading bytes from x509 certificate payload, and I need to parse the extensions part in it.

While i'm reading the bytes, I can't find the length of the whole extensions list size **or** either how to access per each extension from the list.

Attached images with the extensions bytes and a single extension as a byte array

[image]

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: according to your dump, the length of the Extensions structure is 240 bytes (0xF0). But I still didn't get your question. What you are trying accomplish? What programming language you use?

Comment: @CryptoGuy how can you see that 0xF0 is the length?
Java, and i'm trying to read the values of each extension

Comment: In fact, your outer extension structure begins at 0x0AEF byte and payload begins at 0x0AF2. Sorry, I'm not familiar with Java. You simply need to instantiate an `X509Certificate` object in Java and there should be `Extensions` (or something like this) property that contains decoded extensions.

Comment: @CryptoGuy 
OK, so what can I do with this information? How can I decide how to split these extensions ?